# Realm life cycle - dealing with closed/invalid instances in android

Tags: java, android, realm

The realm java docs recommend associating a realm instance to an `Activity`/`Fragment's` life cycle such that a realm is opened/closed when the `Activity`/`Fragment` is created/destroyed.

Let's say a user interaction on the `Activity` triggers a bunch of chained asynchronous/callback-based code that eventually issue reads/writes on the realm instance associated with the `Activity`.

If the user quits the activity immediately after interacting and the realm instance is closed as part of the `Activity's` `onDestroy`, what would be a good way to ensure that transactions/queries on the closed instance fail silently given that it's a nested callback chain.

Checking if a realm instance is closed/valid before calling any method on it is tedious.

At the same time, opening a realm instance and closing it just to write/read something might be expensive.

What would be a good way to avoid crashes like these?

Comment: `a bunch of chained asynchronous/callback-based code` shoud be a handled by a backround service which can get its own Realm instance reference. `that eventually issue reads/writes on the realm instance associated with the activity` Realm observers registered in the activity will react to data changes in the Realm. If the activity is alive, changes will be shown in the UI. If it died, nobody cares.

Comment: not every realm access can be delegated to a background service.

Comment: You're going to have to explain why you think that. Why wouldn't it work in your case? You'd be accessing the same underlying data from all threads.

Comment: I'm with @EugenPechanec . You mention "crashes".  Crashes?  If you can show a stacktrace, we can be of much more help.  Opening and closing a Realm that is open, elsewhere, in your app's process is very, very inexpensive, FWIW.  And if you really need to prevent callbacks to destroyed components (Activities, etc), use `SoftReferences` (definitely not something I usually recommend)

Comment: `Checking if a realm instance is closed/valid before calling any method on it is tedious.` You don't have to do that either. Before every operation call `Realm.getInstance()` and after you're done just close it. Realm instances are reference counted. And as long as one handle remains opened, opening more handles (from the same thread) is virtually free.

Comment: I would have to see more code than no code to know what's up, but generally you can  open and close Realm in a finally block for writes on background threads

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the basic question, here, is: "how do I prevent callbacks to dead components?".  The answer is in the Realm documentation, [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#register-a-callback):  You must unregister listeners when the component exits (`onPause`, `onStop`, or `onDestroy`).

The issue of whether the Realm is open or not, if I understand the question correctly, is a red-herring.  Listeners must be unregistered.

Comment: Personally I prefer to unregister in `onDestroy`, but good answer.